# why do I get an error of undefined variable when I define it in the constructor of the class?

Tags: php, oop, class

From the following `html` , the data from the text-field is served by `action_script.php` :

```
<form method='post' action='action_script.php'>
        <input type='text' name='text_field' id='text_field' />
        <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

`action_script.php` contains the following code :

```
<?php
class Tester {
    private $text_field;

    public function __construct() {
        $text_field = $_POST['text_field'];
    }

    public function print_data() {
        echo $text_field; # LINE NUMBER 10
    }
}

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->print_data();
```

I try to print the *data sent* from the html in `action_script.php` but I get the following warning/error :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: text_field in E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\htdocs\php\action_script.php on line 10
```

Why is that ?

Comment: You are using a variable that might not have been set to a value in the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of class you must refer to your member properties using `$this->`, like

```
<?php
class Tester {
    private $text_field;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->text_field = $_POST['text_field'];
    }

    public function print_data() {
        echo $this->text_field; # LINE NUMBER 10
    }
}

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->print_data();
```

You should also check if `$_POST['text_field']` is set before using it

Comment: explain "doesn't help"? pay attenton that it must be `$this->text_field` and not `$this->$text_field`. and check if `$_POST['text_field']` is set

Comment: changing from **$this->$text_field** to **$this->text_field** solved my problem, thanks alot.

Answer (score 10):

I was using the `$this` statement but still having the same problem, then I figured out the invoked variable must not have the `$` symbol, as some of the users above mentioned.

For instance, *it must not be* like this:

```
$this->$text_field;
```

This is the **correct way** instead:

```
$this->text_field;
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be -

```
echo $this->text_field;
```

in your `print_data` method and also in your all the other methods...

Use `$this` keyword to access member properties and functions.